# I did not understand how to use chars in switches

Tags: c, char, switch-statement

I just started the C language as my first language to seriously learn. I wanted to learn how switch works and I can do it with int values. When I try to use char, I did not get how it works.

Here is what I tried:

```
char class;
scanf("%s", class);
switch(class){
    case 'm': printf("Math!\n"); break;
}
```

The things I have tried are:

1. Using "%c" instead of "%s" in scanf
2. I made the 'char class;' --> 'char class[2];', it said that switch case needed int value
3. I changed it back, then I put a '&' front of 'class' in scanf function and it worked.

I made it work with trying but I didn't understand why it didn't work or why it worked last time I tried it. I thought that we only use '&' with integers.

Any help is more than welcomed, sorry if this is a stupid question but I searched the web and wasn't able to find an answer (Maybe I don't know the correct thing to search for, English is not my native language)

-Thank you

Comment: `scanf("%c", &class);` :D

Comment: Anytime you have a problem involving `scanf`, you either have a problem with `scanf` or the processing of the result. Hard code the value for `class` and skip `scanf`. If you cannot reproduce the problem, then skip `switch` and solve the problem with `scanf`.

Comment: `char` (in your snippet above and generally) is just a "small int"... do not confuse with arrays of char or char pointers being used for text. You use `&` in scanf for ints (`scanf("%d", &i)`), use `&` in scanf for "small ints" (`scanf("%c", &c)`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, several things to clarify...

For `scanf`, both of the `%c` and `%s` conversion specifiers expect their corresponding argument to have type "pointer to `char`" (`char *`); however, what that pointer means and how `scanf` behaves is different between the two.

In the case of `%c`, you pass a pointer to a single `char` object, and the next character read from the input stream (whitespace or not) will be stored to it.  If you want `scanf` to skip over leading whitespace and read the next *non*-whitespace character, put a blank space before the `%c` conversion specifier in the format string, like so:

```
scanf( " %c", &class ); // read the next non-whitespace character into class
```

To obtain the pointer to your target object, use the `&` operator as shown above.

In the case of `%s`, you pass a pointer to the first element of an *array* of `char`; `scanf` will skip over any leading whitespace, then read and store a *sequence* of non-whitespace characters to that array, stopping when it sees a whitespace character.  If your input contains the sequence

```
'\n', ' ', 'T', 'h', 'i', 's', ' ', 'i', 's', ' ', 'a', ' ', 't', 'e', 's', 't', '\n'
```

The `%s` specifier tells `scanf` to read and discard the leading `'\n'` and `' '`, then read the string `"This"` into your array, leaving the following in the input stream:

```
' ', 'i', 's', ' ', 'a', ' ', 't', 'e', 's', 't', '\n'
```

Here's where things get confusing, though - when you pass an array expression as the argument, you *don't* use the `&` operator:

```
char string[21]; // large enough for a 20-character string
...
scanf( "%s", string );
```

The expression `string` in the `scanf` call is converted ("decays") from type "21-element array of `char`" to "pointer to `char`", and its value is the address of the first element of the array.  It's exactly equivalent to writing

```
scanf( "%s", &string[0] );
```

Having said all that...

`scanf` is an *awful* tool for reading interactive input.  It's convenient if you can *guarantee* your input will always be well-formed, but otherwise it's a lot of work to detect and handle badly formed input. For reading individual characters from standard input, you'd be better off using `getchar` (or `fgetc`):

```
/**
 * getchar() returns an int, not a char, since it needs to be able to 
 * return EOF.
 */
int c;

/**
 * Read one character at a time from standard input until we see a 
 * non-whitespace character
 */
do                            
{                             
  c = getchar();
} while ( c != EOF && isspace( c ) ); 

/**
 * And now we can switch on c
 */
switch( c )
{
  case 'm': printf( "Math!\n" ); break;
  ...
  case EOF: printf( "oopsie\n" ); break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with your switch, it's your `scanf` that's the problem.

Let's start with what you wrote:

```
char class;
scanf("%s", class);
```

`%s` means string, which expects a buffer to write into given by a pointer. Because in C/C++ numerical arguments sent into a `vararg` (which is what `scanf` uses) get converted to an `int` (or whatever the CPU register size is), it will have the correct size to look like a pointer, and when it tries to write into it it should probably crash with an access violation since it's an invalid pointer.

Now you're obviously trying to read a character, so `%c` should be obvious to use, but in the list of things you tried you said you still passed the character instead of a pointer to it, so the correct code is:

```
char class;
scanf("%c", &class);
```

This should also explain why the 3rd option you tried seemed to work, and why in fact it overwrote memory outside of your variables. Since you're not using many variables and your stack is rather large, you didn't crash with an access violation or stack overflow, but you absolutely corrupted your (luckily unused) memory.

Comment: The question is tagged C, not C++, and whether an `int` and a `char *` are the same size is implementation-dependent.

Comment: It doesn't matter if it's implementation dependent, the assumption is inside `scanf` itself.

Comment: The statement “… get converted to an `int`, it will have the correct size to look like a pointer…” is false in C implementations where an `int` and `char *` are not the same size.

Comment: This guy is trying to *learn* the language, are you seriously bringing this up here? Fine, you're right, I'll clarify that I meant register size instead of `int`, as if that'll make things clearer for him. And in fact I thought `nint` as I wrote that, but there is no such thing in C.